# item2 path not recognised as a clickable path

Tags: elixir, iterm2

when I command-click a path in iTerm2, the click opens Atom with the corresponding file :)

but my application logger is showing paths like, lib/app/helpers/date_helper.ex:213 in the iterm2 console.

These paths are not recognised as an path. So a command-click doesn't work.
How to tell iTerm2, that as lib/app/users/user.ex:100 is a path and line number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first register Atom as the default application for `.ex` files with OSX (by doubly clicking on a `.ex` file in a Finder window, for example).

I tested this and before I registered a default application, nothing happened when command-clicking on lines such as `lib/test.ex:32`, but after registering it, it now opens the files in the application I specified (providing the file exists).

For anyone reading this that wants to open the file in the same terminal session, [setting up a coprocess](https://coderwall.com/p/5hp1yg/iterm2-cmd-click-to-open-file-in-vim-in-terminal) is useful:

> Click on: Preferences -> Profiles -> Advanced
>
> Under "Semantic History", choose "Run coprocess..". In the text field,
>   put:
>
> echo vim \1 +\2